# Is there a way to print all the values of the array to an output file?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, file-io

I made a *RainFall* class that stores the amount (in inches) of rain through the year (12 values in total). I have it working, but now I need to print those values to an outputFile (I called it *RainFall.txt*). When I run the code and check the file, it only stores the first value of the array.

I've already tried with `try and catch` methods but it does not print anything.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat; 

public class RainFallMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Array representing rainfall figures
        // position correlates to the month
        double[] thisYear = { 1.6, 2.1, 1.7, 3.5, 2.6, 3.7, 3.9, 2.6, 2.9, 4.3, 2.4, 3.7 };
        RainfallClass r = new RainfallClass(thisYear);
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("RainFall.txt"); 
               for (int i = 0; i < thisYear.length; i++)
               {
                   outputFile.println(thisYear[i]);
                   outputFile.close();
               }
```

The output file should have all 12 values listed.

Comment: Check where you're closing the file

Comment: To be specific, move `outputFile.close()` outside the for loop.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't noticed it. Such a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Output file should be closed only after you finish all the writing.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // Some statements
    for (int i = 0; i < thisYear.length; i++){
        outputFile.println(thisYear[i]);    
    }
    outputFile.close(); // Moved out of the for loop
    // Some more statements if there. 
}
```